# Show only newly added lines of logfile in terminal

Tags: bash, shell

I use `tail -f` to show the contents of a logfile.

What I want is when the logfile content changes, instead of appending the new lines to my screen, only the newly added lines should be shown on my screen.

So as if a clearscreen was made every time before printing the new lines.

I tried to find a solution by web search but couldn't find anything useful.

**edit:**
In my case it happens that several lines will be added at once (it is a php error logfile). So I am looking for a solution where more than the single last line can be shown on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
$ `watch 'tac FILE | grep -m1 -C2 PATTERN | tac'`
where
*PATTERN* is any keyword (or regexp) to identify errors you seek in the log,
`tac` prints the lines in reverse,
`-m` is a max count of matching lines to grep,
`-C` is any number of lines of context (before and after the match) to show (optional).

That would be similar to
$ `tail -f FILE | grep -C2 PATTERN`
if you didn't mind just appending occurrences to the output in real-time.

But if you don't know any generic PATTERN to look for at all,
you'd have to just follow all the updates as the logfile grows:
$ `tail -n0 -f FILE`

Or even, create a copy of the logfile and then do a diff:

1. Copy: `cp file.log{,.old}`
2. Refresh the webpage with your .php code (or whatever, to trigger the error)
3. Run: `diff file.log{,.old}`
   (or, if you prefer sort to diff:  $ `sort file.log{,.old} | uniq -u`)

The curly braces is shorthand for both filenames (see *Brace Expansion* in $ `man bash`)

If you must avoid any temp copies, store the line count in memory:

1. `z=$(grep -c ^ file.log)`
2. Refresh the webpage to trigger an error
3. `tail -n +$z file.log`

The latter approach can be built upon, to create a custom scripting solution more suitable for your needs (check timestamps, clear screen, filter specific errors, etc). For example, to only show the lines that belong to the last error message in the log file updated in real-time:

$ `clear; z=$(grep -c ^ FILE); while true; do d=$(date -r FILE); sleep 1; b=$(date -r FILE); if [ "$d" != "$b" ]; then clear; tail -n +$z FILE; z=$(grep -c ^ FILE); fi; done`
where
`FILE` is, obviously, your log file name;
`grep -c ^ FILE` counts *all* lines in a file (that is almost, but not entirely unlike `cat FILE|wc -l` that would only count newlines);
`sleep 1` sets the pause/delay between checking the file timestamps to 1 second, but you could change it to even a floating point number (the less the interval, the higher the CPU usage).
To simplify any repetitive invocations in future, you could save this compound command in a Bash script that could take a target logfile name as an argument, or define a shell function, or create an alias in your shell, or just reverse-search your bash history with CTRL+R. Hope it helps!

Comment: I like the approach. Although I have to issue this command after every error that happened, otherwise it will sum up all error messages that happened since the last copy of the logfile.

Comment: @larwain If you already know some keywords to identify the specific error to watch, you could also use `grep` and just filter your way through the file or pipe out the output into grep, e.g. `tail ... | grep ...`. Hope all messages in the log have the timestamps to help you further!

Comment: I understand. For comfort reasons I am looking for something like a live-preview. That is, I don't have to re-type any commands, instead it will just keep displaying the last error message from the log file whenever I look at it.

Comment: @larwain Try `watch 'tac FILE | grep -m1 -C2 PATTERN | tac'` where PATTERN is any keyword to identify error messages that you seek. I will update my anaswer with more explanation.

Comment: Well in my case there isn't any PATTERN that I am looking for. Just the newest error message from the log file, which consists of one or more lines and doesn't have any specific pattern, keywords or formatting.

Comment: @larwain I see... and something simple like `watch tail -n20 FILE` isn't ideal for you either because your need is to display only the last error message rather than last n number of lines, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Log messages can be hard to read and it can be very hard to tell where the last error message begins. That's why it would be great to only see the lines that belong to the last error message and nothing else.

Comment: @larwain Ok, i have found some time and added a more compound example of what will probably be the most helpful, please check it out above, at the end of my answer..

Comment: The solution sounds great, I just can't get it working because it keeps saying `bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`done'`. How can I get through this?

Comment: @larwain Hmm, works fine for me.. Did you miss a word 'do' or a semicolon? What's your OS version? Note, it all goes in on a single line -- one long compound command comprised of a list of smaller commands. Copy-pasting it from a web browser could mangle up some special  characters such as quotes, so try to carefully type it in manually, double-check. Do simple test: `while true; do sleep 1; date; if true; then clear; sleep 1; echo TEST; fi; done` and understand what it does and how it works to verify syntax. Good luck!

Comment: Alright, I had some misconfiguration in my .bashrc which I was able to fix. Now also your script seems to work exactly like I wanted it to work. Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: Maybe you can edit your answer to make it look a bit nicer?

Comment: Also I added some more commands at the beginning, to better fit my work process: `filename=logfiles/"$(command ls -t logfiles/ | head -n1)";
clear;
echo $filename`
You can add this to your answer if you want.

Comment: Really glad that you figured that out, and it worked for you. I'd rather not edit my answer now, as it feels more useful this way, covering multiple ways of increasing complexity to approach the problem and work one's way through the logs, depending on individual situation, whoever may run into it in the future. have a great holidays!

Answer (score 1):

The `watch` command in combination with the `tail` command shows the last line of a log file with the intervall of every 2 seconds. Basically it doesn't refresh whenever a new line is appended to the log file but since you could specifiy an intervall it might help you for your use case.

```
watch -t tail -1 <path_to_logfile>
```

If you need a faster intervall like every 0.5 seconds, then you could specify it with the 'n' option i.e.:

```
watch -t -n 0.5 tail -1 <path_to_logfile>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited my question to clarify a bit...

Comment: If the new added lines to the logfile have the same timestamp you could extract the last timestamp. And finally use the timestamp with the grep command to show only the last lines of the file

Comment: Unfortunately not all lines in the logfile have a timestamp...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are (or were) looking for:

```
#!/bin/sh
logfile=/var/log/yourlogfile
lastpos="$(stat -c%s "$logfile")"   # or 0 if you want to start from zero
while true; do
  newpos="$(stat -c%s "$logfile")"
  if [ "$newpos" != "$lastpos" ]; then
    clear
    tail -c+"$lastpos" "$logfile"
    lastpos="$newpos"
  fi
  sleep 10  
done
```

Depending on your needs, it might be too complex or not enough. The key point is that I take the size of the file using `stat -c%s` and jump to that position using `tail -c+number`. This is far more efficient than any diff or per-line operation.

I think, for loglines it is good enough, but you should note that `tail` and `stat` are not an atomic operation. It might happen that some output is doubled in this script, if the size grows between the `stat` call and `tail`. If you swap the two commands, you risk losing lines in the same way.

I use this code before and after a specific cron call, to be able to `grep` for warnings and errors and do a proper alert in that case only for the most recent call.